# Delphi Indy TIdHttp and multipart/x-mixed-replace with Text and jpeg image

Tags: http, delphi, indy, idhttp

I´m using a Dahua Facial terminal and it has a API like (CGI style) and a SDK. i asked some questions about dll convertions, but now i´m trying to use de API too.

The API to monitoring the events handled by Facial is

> [http://192.168.1.201/cgi-bin/snapManager.cgi?action=attachFileProc&Flags[0]=Event&Events=[AccessControl]](http://192.168.1.201/cgi-bin/snapManager.cgi?action=attachFileProc&Flags%5B0%5D=Event&Events=%5BAccessControl%5D)

Is a multipart/x-mixed-replace response how return a first bondary as text/plain with the event data and a bondary with a image/jpeg with the snapshot of the event.

Using the info online about Indy and some useful posts made by Lebeau i cad read the text data using idHttp.IoHanlder.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8)

I tryed to read the next bondary (image) with idHttp.IOHandler.ReadByte, ReadBytes, ReadStream but not sucess.

Here is the response using idHttp.IoHandler.ReadLn

```
--myboundary
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 1035

Events[0].Alive=100
Events[0].CardName=Joao Test
Events[0].CardNo=0B8748EB
Events[0].CardType=0
Events[0].CreateTime=1616297700
Events[0].Door=0
Events[0].ErrorCode=0
Events[0].Method=15
Events[0].ReaderID=1
Events[0].Similarity=99
Events[0].SnapPath=/var/tmp/partsnap96.jpg
Events[0].Status=1
Events[0].Type=Entry
Events[0].UTC=1616297700
Events[0].UserID=1
Events[0].UserType=0

--myboundary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 54235

����

(1#%(:3=<9387@H\N@DWE78PmQW_bghg>Mqypdx\egc//cB8Bcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc//cB8Bcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc��

%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������������������������������������������������������������

$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������
�XQz �?m�c$[J��5"�Hz�~5���m+��b{�����{��n��*p�p*�8�bx��
`3mjLQ��9CB���T���D���'ޥAY\ų���>�*��c�U���h�R�%��je�W��*]�m�p��m?��c6�?��b��R��1N�.(��.)إ�
u\,8�
)�ny�ڌү
@
#��
L�rɳ���B�Ns�� S�K��
�i�F��Z�af�
������ޭ�T�
/l�i]Q��l������
C�RS�
ʛO^�ҫ���
h�

P)@�
pN��
\S���0�1K�
f2N�⫑S�-�LF-�Y�8?0��.�?[�nE[��t[��s�w�h��_���y�[�R�*��=je ������4�M��,?�x��Ƣ�Sל�t8�F�
ZJZ
(��R�E
)h�bR�K@����
p�S����)تb���x1�O��(��i�1����5��r=i��i�B�A��J�{���ںT5s��_��
Q@-�
Z1J

x�i�i�S�NU��
�Kf=9=Pƺ�s�ٿ��N����uS�Tj��#��d��-N-����gw�W5�0*z0��=&m��=T��S�����
x�`JpJxZpZ"��i
p���@
<S7
P���R�a�wP"���� %!�Q�
��`�M�6��wⵍfjJb�I�������{�h/���ڞ�r�Q��Ta�ϫ�7E��o�����5%���X��C�
�v�G�rO���
��徸�(�O�T�4�4��ц��j8�
��3sM�X�'�G��ڪξ\�/L|��i����I?+|�Z�
�?��K[M��L7�^
K�@d�Hb��q߯�V�'|a��C�E�Z�+�
f�&����`'�ϑ��E�r>�Ƶ'Q�7~��<r}��XT�+������pHQۭ
```

I´m creating a class to implement the API and SDK, in this case (API) to manage the events i wrote a thread class to consume the Event API and syncronize the data when a event occur, the idHttp is owned by the thread class and it inside a TDispositivo class, so i run one thread class for each TDispositivo included on main class.

Here is the Execute code from the thread. (ignoring the image data because i do not now how to get it rigth.

```
procedure TMonitor.Execute;
var
  Ret, URL, Chave, Valor : String;
  I, isInteger : Integer;
  Concluido : boolean;
  Tentativas: Integer;
begin
  Tentativas := 3;
  fAtivo := True;
  FContador := 0; //zerando contador
  //executa enquanto fAtivo for True e terminated for False
  while fAtivo and not self.Terminated do
    begin
      if fOwner.alive then
        begin
          //preparando URL
          With fOwner.Config do
            begin
              Url := 'http://'+ IP + ifthen(PortaWeb>=0,':'+PortaWeb.ToString,'')+'/cgi-bin/snapManager.cgi?action=attachFileProc&Flags[0]=Event&Events=[AccessControl]';
            end;
          //Incrementando contado
          Inc(fContador);
          //Efetuando o GET dentro de um try except para evitar interrupcao na thread
          Try
            ret := fHttp.Get(Url);
          except

          End;
          fOwner.doGet(fhttp.ResponseCode, fhttp.ResponseText);
          //tratando erros http
          if fHttp.ResponseCode <> 200 then
            begin
              case fHttp.ResponseCode of
                400: Erro(740,'Chamada ao terminal mal formada');
                401: Erro(741,'Chamada ao terminal não autorizada');
                403: Erro(743,'Recurso do servidor proibido');
                404: Erro(744,'Recurso do terminal não encontrado');
                500: Erro(750,'Erro interno no processamento de chamadas do terminal');
                501: Erro(751,'Recurso do terminal não implementado');
              end;
              if (fContador >= Tentativas) then
                begin
                  Erro(700,'Falha ao conectar o dispositivo. Número de tentativas excedido');
                  fContador := 0;
                  //verificando se vai continuar tentando se reconectar
                  if fOwner.Config.Reconectar then
                    begin
                      Log('Aguardando para tentar reconectar o monitor ...');
                      Sleep(fOwner.Config.TempoEsperaReconectar);
                    end
                  else
                    begin
                      Log('Finalizando monitoramento por falha de comunicação');
                      Self.Stop;
                    end;
                end;
            end
          else
            begin
              //zerando contador após uma conexão bem sucedida;
              FContador := 0;
              //para evitar final do chunk ou close gracefully
              try
                if IsHeaderMediaType(fHttp.Response.ContentType, 'multipart') then
                  begin
                    i := 0;
                    Concluido := False;
                    repeat
                      if (i >= 35) Or Concluido then
                        begin
                          //tirando snap antes de processar o evento para ver se diminui o delay
                          if FOwner.Config.SnapshotEvento then
                            fOwner.getSnapshot;
                          Synchronize(Evento);
                          Concluido := False;
                          i := 0;
                        end;
                      fLinha := fHttp.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
                      if Pos('Content-Length', fLinha) > 0 then
                        begin
                          i := 0;
                          Concluido := False;
                          fEvento.Limpar;
                        end
                      Else if Pos('Events[', fLinha) > 0 then
                        begin
                          if fOwner.Config.Depurar then
                            Log(fLinha);
                          Inc(I);
                          Chave := Trim(retPar(1,'=',retPar(2,'.',fLinha)));
                          Valor := Trim(retPar(2,'=',fLinha));
                          if Valor = '' then
                            Valor := '0';
                          With fEvento do
                            begin
                              if Chave = 'Alive' then
                                Alive := ifthen(Valor = '',0,Valor.ToInteger)
                              else if Chave = 'CardName' then
                                CardName := ifthen(Trim(Valor) = '0','Não identificado',trim(Valor))
                              else if Chave = 'CardNo' then
                                begin
                                  if TryStrToInt(Valor, isInteger) then
                                    CardNo :=  ifthen(Valor = '', '-1', Valor)
                                  else
                                    CardNo :=  WiegandHexToInt(Valor).ToString;
                                end
                              else if Chave = 'CardType' then
                                CardType := ifthen(Valor = '', -1, Valor.ToInteger)
                              else if Chave = 'CreateTime' then
                                CreateTime := UnixToDateTime(Valor.ToInt64, False)
                              else if Chave = 'Door' then
                                Door := ifThen(Valor = '',-1, Valor.ToInteger)
                              else if Chave = 'ErrorCode' then
                                ErrorCode := ifThen(Valor = '',-1, Valor.ToInteger)
                              else if Chave = 'EventBaseInfo.Action' then
                                EventBaseAction := Valor
                              else if Chave = 'EventBaseInfo.Code' then
                                EventBaseCode := Valor
                              else if Chave = 'EventBaseInfo.Index' then
                                EventBaseIndex := ifThen(Valor = '',-1, Valor.ToInteger)
                              else if Chave = 'Method' then
                                Metodo := ifThen(Valor = '',-1, Valor.ToInteger)
                              else if Chave = 'ReaderID' then
                                LeitorID := ifThen(Valor = '',-1, Valor.ToInteger)
                              else if Chave = 'Similarity' then
                                Similaridade := ifthen(Valor = '', 0, Valor.ToInteger)
                              else if Chave = 'SnapPath' then
                                snappath := Valor
                              else if Chave = 'Status' then
                                Status := ifthen(Valor = '', -1, Valor.ToInteger)
                              else if Chave = '.Type' then
                                TipoAcesso := Valor
                              else if Chave = 'UTC' then
                                DataHora := UnixToDateTime(Valor.ToInt64, False)
                              else if Chave = 'UserID' then
                                UserID := ifthen(Valor = '', -1, Valor.ToInteger)
                              else if Chave = 'UserType' then
                                begin
                                  i := 34;
                                  Concluido := True;
                                  UserType := ifthen(Valor = '', -1, Valor.ToInteger);
                                end;
                            end;
                        end;
                    until fhttp.IOHandler.ClosedGracefully;
                  end;
              except

              end;
            end;
          inherited;
        end
      else
        begin
          //dispositivo não respondeu ao ping
          //verificando se vai continuar tentando se reconectar
          if fOwner.Config.Reconectar then
            begin
              Log('Aguardando para tentar reconectar o monitor ...');
              Sleep(fOwner.Config.TempoEsperaReconectar);
            end
          else
            begin
              Log('Finalizando monitoramento por falha de comunicação');
              Self.Stop;
            end;
          inherited;
        end;
    end;
  //rotina de finalização da thread
  if FHttp.Connected then
    begin
      try
        Fhttp.Disconnect;
      except

      end;
    end;
end;
```

First question, Can i do it ?  Indy can do It ? Any suggestions ?

Second question, I observe the loop to retrive data when GET is running raise a Close gracefully when i try to readLn after the data is end. In Firefox the GET still running after the image and still working, in my case, the GET is finished and the threand.execute call GET again.

Is possible to keep the GET running avoiding premature interruption and processes the new data when present ?

**EDIT**: When this part of the code run, the line `NewDecoder := TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).ReadBody(BodyStream, MsgEnd);` raises a close gracefully, looking deeper on Indy code i found a `TIOHandler.ReadLn` how execute `CheckForDisconnect(True,True)` when `LTerm = -1` and this break the execution without retrive the last bytes of data.

Thinking about this i´m suspect has a rellation with the `Responde.KeepAlive` is always `False` ans the `Connection` content is always `close` it´s explain why Decoder.Readybody raises a `Close gracefully` and break my execution.

But, if i run the api call on eg. Firefox, the connection still running after the FF get the image and only interrupts whenreachs a timeout.

Is it possible something on headers sended by terminal ? or the way how idHttp parse the headers data ?

```
//part  of code after http.get

              mcptAttachment: begin
                BodyStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
                try
                  BodyStream.Position := 0;

                  NewDecoder := TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).ReadBody(BodyStream, MsgEnd); //<-- here comes a close gracefully               

                  jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
                  try
                    BodyStream.Position := 0;
                    jpg.LoadFromStream(BodyStream);
                    jpg.SaveToFile('C:\Producao\API_SDK\Facial\teste.jpg');
                  finally
                    jpg.Free;
                    Decoder.Free;
                    Decoder := NewDecoder;
                  end;
                finally
                  BodyStream.Free;
                end;
              end;


//part of the code of tIOHandler.ReadLn

    // ReadFromSource blocks - do not call unless we need to
    else if LTermPos = -1 then begin
      // ReadLn needs to call this as data may exist in the buffer, but no EOL yet disconnected
      CheckForDisconnect(True,True); //The execution stops here whiout return the last bytes and premature finishing the code above with a close gracefully
      // Can only return -1 if timeout
      FReadLnTimedOut := ReadFromSource(True, ATimeout, False) = -1;
      if (not FReadLnTimedOut) and (ATimeout >= 0) then begin
        if GetElapsedTicks(LReadLnStartTime) >= UInt32(ATimeout) then begin
          FReadLnTimedOut := True;
        end;
      end;
      if FReadLnTimedOut then begin
        Result := '';
        Exit;
      end;
```

**EDIT**: Using the [New TIdHTTP hoNoReadMultipartMIME flag](https://www.indyproject.org/2014/03/05/new-tidhttp-honoreadmultipartmime-flag/) sample, i wrote a test app to try get the image from the boundary

```
var
  Boundary, Line: string;
  TCPStream: TIdTCPStream;
  NewDecoder, Decoder: TIdMessageDecoder;
  MsgEnd: Boolean;
  BodyStream: TStream;
  Jpg: TJpegImage;
begin
  {
    The code below comes from Indy Project Blog by Remy Lebeau
    This connection requires Digest Auth, so i set BasicAuth to False, put the flag hoInProcessAuth
    And implement the OnAuthorization and OnSelectAuthorization, the select is needed to do something to the Authorization works,
    do not know why.
   }
  HTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoInProcessAuth, hoForceEncodeParams, hoNoReadMultipartMIME];
  HTTP.Get('http://192.168.1.205/cgi-bin/snapManager.cgi?action=attachFileProc&Flags[0]=Event&Events=[AccessControl]');

  //Here the response always return HTTP.Response.KeepAlive FALSE, so i exclude it from test
  if IsHeaderMediaType(HTTP.Response.ContentType, 'multipart') then //and HTTP.Response.KeepAlive
    begin
      Boundary := ExtractHeaderSubItem(HTTP.Response.ContentType, 'boundary', QuoteHTTP);
      repeat
        Line := HTTP.IOHandler.ReadLn;
      until (Line = ('--' + Boundary)) or (Line = ('--' + Boundary + '--'));

      TCPStream := TIdTCPStream.Create(HTTP);
      try
        Decoder := TIdMessageDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
        try
          TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).MIMEBoundary := Boundary;

          MsgEnd := False;
          repeat
            TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).SourceStream := TCPStream;
            TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).FreeSourceStream := False;

            Decoder.ReadHeader;
            case Decoder.PartType of
              mcptText: begin
                BodyStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
                try
                  NewDecoder := TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).ReadBody(BodyStream, MsgEnd);
                  try
                    BodyStream.Position := 0;
                    mLog.Lines.LoadFromStream(BodyStream);      //<-- OK i got the text data from body and showing in a memo
                  finally
                    Decoder.Free;
                    Decoder := NewDecoder;
                  end;
                finally
                  BodyStream.Free;
                end;
              end;

              mcptAttachment: begin
                BodyStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
                try
                  BodyStream.Position := 0;
                  NewDecoder := TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).ReadBody(BodyStream, MsgEnd); //<-- here comes a close gracefully,
                  //so i debug the ReadBody and found a exception on line 438 of idMessadeCoderMime
                  //          LLine := ReadLnRFC(VMsgEnd, LF, '.', LEncoding{$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}, LEncoding{$ENDIF}); {do not localize}
                  //When it try to read a exception occurs and the connection closes gracefully
                  //but it read a lot of data befora except, so i thinking is something about a end of msg missing or misformed
                  jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
                  try
                    BodyStream.Position := 0;
                    jpg.LoadFromStream(BodyStream);
                    jpg.SaveToFile('C:\Producao\API_SDK\Facial\teste.jpg');
                  finally
                    jpg.Free;
                    Decoder.Free;
                    Decoder := NewDecoder;
                  end;
                finally
                  BodyStream.Free;
                end;
              end;

              mcptIgnore: begin
                FreeAndNil(Decoder);
                Decoder := TIdMessageDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
                TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).MIMEBoundary := Boundary;
              end;

              mcptEOF: begin
                FreeAndNil(Decoder);
                MsgEnd := True;
              end;
            end;
          until (Decoder = nil) or MsgEnd;
        finally
          Decoder.Free;
        end;
      finally
        TCPStream.Free;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

The part of the code `mcptAttachment` when `NewDecoder := Decoder.ReadBody(BodyStream, MsgEnd);` is called, the readbody funtion run, reading the bytes until it crashes before reach the 'Content-Length' size.
I´m trying to isolate when it crashes, but one thing is for sure, the error occurs when it try to read the next data. but i can´t find the trigger for the exception on indy source yet

**EDIT**: Got a imagem but can´t keep reading until server close connection cause the response alredy comes closed.

**Workin Code**

```
var
  Boundary, Line: string;
  TCPStream: TIdTCPStream;
  NewDecoder, Decoder: TIdMessageDecoder;
  MsgEnd: Boolean;
  BodyStream: TStream;
  Jpg: TJpegImage;
begin
  HTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoInProcessAuth, hoForceEncodeParams, hoNoReadMultipartMIME];
  HTTP.Get('http://192.168.1.205/cgi-bin/snapManager.cgi?action=attachFileProc&Flags[0]=Event&Events=[AccessControl]');
  if IsHeaderMediaType(HTTP.Response.ContentType, 'multipart') then
    begin
      Boundary := ExtractHeaderSubItem(HTTP.Response.ContentType, 'boundary', QuoteHTTP);
      repeat
        Line := HTTP.IOHandler.ReadLn;
      until (Line = ('--' + Boundary)) or (Line = ('--' + Boundary + '--'));

      TCPStream := TIdTCPStream.Create(HTTP);
      try
        Decoder := TIdMessageDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
        try
          TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).MIMEBoundary := Boundary;

          MsgEnd := False;
          repeat
            TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).SourceStream := TCPStream;
            TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).FreeSourceStream := False;
            if not http.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
              begin
                Decoder.ReadHeader;
                case Decoder.PartType of
                  mcptText: begin
                    BodyStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
                    try
                      NewDecoder := TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).ReadBody(BodyStream, MsgEnd);
                      try
                        BodyStream.Position := 0;
                        mEvent.Lines.LoadFromStream(BodyStream);
                      finally
                        Decoder.Free;
                        Decoder := NewDecoder;
                      end;
                    finally
                      BodyStream.Free;
                    end;
                  end;

                  mcptAttachment: begin
                    BodyStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
                    http.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToStream(BodyStream);
                    try
                      BodyStream.Position := 0;
                      jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
                      try
                        jpg.LoadFromStream(BodyStream);
                        JvImage1.Picture.Assign(jpg);
                        jpg.SaveToFile('C:\Producao\API-SDK\Facial\teste.jpg');
                      finally
                        jpg.Free;
                        FreeAndNil(Decoder);
                        Decoder := TIdMessageDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
                        TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).MIMEBoundary := Boundary;
                      end;
                    finally
                      BodyStream.Free;
                    end;
                  end;

                  mcptIgnore: begin
                    mLog.Lines.Add('Ignore');
                    FreeAndNil(Decoder);
                    Decoder := TIdMessageDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
                    TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).MIMEBoundary := Boundary;
                  end;

                  mcptEOF: begin
                    mLog.Lines.Add('Fim');
                    FreeAndNil(Decoder);
                    MsgEnd := True;
                  end;
                end;
              end
            else
              begin
                http.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect(False,True);
                msgend := True
              end;
          until (Decoder = nil) or MsgEnd;
        finally
          Decoder.Free;
        end;
      finally
        TCPStream.Free;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for can be done with `TIdHTTP`, but it takes some extra work. Details are in the following blog article on Indy's website:

https://www.indyproject.org/2014/03/05/new-tidhttp-honoreadmultipartmime-flag/

In a nutshell, you need to enable the `hoNoReadMultipartMIME` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property, so that `TIdHTTP.Get()` won't try to read the MIME data from the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` after receiving the HTTP headers. That will allow you to read the MIME data yourself. You can use Indy's `TIdMessageDecoderMIME` class to help with that reading.  There is a code example provided in the blog article.

Comment: Remy, i already using the flag hoNoReadMultipartMIME and i stop the use of TIdMessageDecoderMime cause Decoder.ReadBody(BodyStream,MsgEnd) crash on mcptAttachment, The mcptText works fine.  So i change my approach to try something different to try read the jpeg data.

Comment: @JoaoIshiwatari I have never seen `TIdMessageDecoderMIME` crash on attachments. It is the same class that `TIdMessage` uses to parse MIME emails. I've been recommending this approach with `TIdHTTP` for years and never had a problem with it. What is the actual crash you are experiencing?

Comment: I say crash, but isnt a really crash, is a close gracefully, i debug the event, in `Decoder.ReadBody` i seek the source of the wrapped functions until the `TIOHandler.ReadLn` paying attention to `LTermPos` and `LInputBufferSize` for each time, when the loop is close to end, and `LTermPos = -1` the routine calls `CheckForDisconnect(True,True)` and raise the Close gracefully and interrupt the processes of the `Decoder.ReadBody` without the data, i´m supposing the last bytes are not read. I will Edit the post to try to explain better.

Comment: @JoaoIshiwatari ideally, it should not be raising an exception unless the socket is being closed before an ending MIME boundary is received. It is not usual (but not illegal) for individual MIME parts to have their own `Content-Length` header. I don't think `TIdMessageDecoderMIME` handles that. I will have to look into it. Please open a ticket at https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues. In the meantime, you know about the `hoNoReadMultipartMIME` flag, so there is nothing stopping you from reading the MIME data from the IOHandler manually. Using `TIdMessageDecoderMIME` is not a requirement.

Comment: the data received has two boundarys for each event, so the first boundary start with 5 lines ( 1 blank line, 2 --myboundary, 3 Content-Type, 4 Content-Length, 5 blank line) after this lines comes the data, on text/plain i receive the `Events[0]` lines and at last `Events[0]` line the end of boundary is the start of the next one with anoter 5 lines, after that start the jpeg data but is endless, not --myboundary-- or myboundary -- or empty line. I use FireFox to see the data comming from device and see the end of image boundary is not there

Comment: @JoaoIshiwatari I know how `multipart/x-mixed-replace` works. Plenty of online docs explain that behavior. So, what is stopping you from reading that data? Use `IOHandler.ReadLn()` in a loop to receive the MIME boundary, then again to receive the part headers, and then if `Content-Length` is present then use `IOHandler.ReadBytes()` or `IOHandler.ReadStream()` with the specified length. Then repeat until the connection is closed.

Comment: Yes i did exactly what you say, but i receive a connection gracefully when i try to read the bytes with a Content-length size or read a stream with a content-length size.  EG `Content-Length: 54235` from jpeg header boundary, so i use `B: TIdBytes` and  call `Http.IOHanlder.ReadBytes(B,54235,False)` i got a close gracefully. As you say, maybe the device close the connection before send all jpeg data, but this behavior isn´t present on firefox test. i know is not a valid campare, but tests the device behavior sending data and the connection status

Comment: @JoaoIshiwatari "*i receive a connection gracefully when i try to read the bytes with a Content-length size or read a stream with a content-length size*" - then either the `Content-Length` is wrong to begin with, or the connection is actually being closed before the end of data is received. Have you verified either of those conditions, such as with Wireshark? For instance, in your 1st example, the text shown for the `text/plain` part is nowhere near 1035 bytes, it is closer to 398 bytes. And the data shown for the `image/jpeg` part is nowhere near 54235 bytes, it is closer to 1248 bytes.

Comment: I have a question about multipar on indy, As i say before, on FF the get keeps ruinning until connection is close, so each new event on device is read by ff and displayed, on the blog sample, after the `http.get` i perform a loop to read the bytes comming until the laste one. after that how can i keep in the loop without close de connection ? cause if i try to read new bytes or try `Decoder.ReadHeader` the close gracefully happens.

Comment: @JoaoIshiwatari "*how can i keep in the loop without close de connection ?*" - you don't have to do anything special, just keep reading, don't close the connection on your end. You are not going to get the error until the server closes the connection on its end. "*if i try to read new bytes or try `Decoder.ReadHeader` the close gracefully happens*" - I already explained that to you earlier. Go re-read my other comments. I'm not going to repeat myself.

Comment: Sorry @RemyLebeau, i understand what you say and i´m glade for your help as always, but what i do not understand is why on FF the response keeps alived and in indy the response comes closed?  Is all i want to undertand, Just to knowledge cause i put a loop to keep calling get after the connection close.

Comment: @JoaoIshiwatari "*why on FF the response keeps alived and in indy the response comes closed*" - I can't answer that. You are just going to have analyze the underlying network traffic for yourself. Obviously, the server is doing something different for Indy than it does for FireFox.  Have you tried pretending to be FireFox by setting the `TIdHTTP.Request.UserAgent` property?

Comment: Using the wireshark i see a red [RST,ACK] linked to a pior [SYN] when i use my app. Using FF the [RST,ACK] does not appear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230287/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-joao-ishiwatari).