# How to get continuous HTTP data?

Tags: http, delphi, stream, multipartform-data, indy

I'm trying to get live trading data from the Internet via HTTP, but it is updated continuously, so if I `GET` the data, it will keep downloading as long as there is data available. Until I stop the downloading stream, then I can access the data.

How to access the stream of data while the downloading is in progress?

I tried using Indy's `TIdHTTP`, so I can use SSL, but I tried the `IdIOHandlerStream`, but it was already used for `IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`. So I'm absolutely clueless here.

This is in response to a `"multipart/form-data"` request.

Please guide me...

```
Lrequest.Values['__RequestVerificationToken'] := RequestVerificationToken;
Lrequest.Values['acct'] := 'demo';
Lrequest.Values['pwd'] := 'demo';

try    
  Response.Text := Onhttp.Post('https://trading/data', Lrequest);
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Time) + ': ' + Response.Text);
except
  on E: Exception do
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(TimeToStr(Time) + ': ' + E.ClassName +
      ' error raised, with message : ' + E.Message);
end;
```

**UPDATE:**

The data is an endless JSON string, like this:

```json
{"id":"data","val":[{"rc":2,"tpc":"\\RealTime\\Global\\SGDIDR.FX","item":[{"val":{"F009":"10454.90","F011":"-33.1"}}]}]}
{"id":"data","val":[{"rc":2,"tpc":"\\RealTime\\Global\\SGDIDR.FX","item":[{"val":{"F009":"10458.80","F011":"-29.2"}}]}]}
```

and so on, and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `TIdIOHandlerStream` to interface with a TCP connection, that is not what it is designed for.  It is meant for performing I/O operations using user-provided `TStream` objects, ie for debugging previously captured sessions.

`TIdHTTP` is not really designed to handle endless HTTP responses in most cases, as you have described.  What is the *exact* format that the server is delivering its live data as?  What do the HTTP response headers look like?  It is really difficult to answer your question without know the *exact* format being used.

However, that being said, there are some cases to consider, depending on what the server is actually sending:

- if the server is using a MIME-based server-push format, like `multipart/x-mixed-replace`, you can enable the `hoNoReadMultipartMIME` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property, and then read the MIME data yourself from the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` after `TIdHTTP.Get()` exits.  For instance, you can use `TIdMessageDecoderMIME` to help you parse the MIME parts, see [New TIdHTTP hoNoReadMultipartMIME flag](https://www.indyproject.org/2014/03/05/new-tidhttp-honoreadmultipartmime-flag/) in Indy's blog, or [Delphi Indy TIdHttp and multipart/x-mixed-replace with Text and jpeg image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66728692/).
- Otherwise, if the server is using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, where each data update is sent as a new HTTP chunk, you can use the `TIdHTTP.OnChunkReceived` event.  Or, you can enable the `hoNoReadChunked` flag in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property, and then read the chunks yourself from the `TIdHTTP.IOHandler` after `TIdHTTP.Get()` exits. See [New TIdHTTP flags and OnChunkReceived event](https://www.indyproject.org/2016/01/10/new-tidhttp-flags-and-onchunkreceived-event/) in Indy's blog.
- Otherwise, you could give `TIdHTTP.Get()` a `TIdEventStream` to write into, and then use that stream's `OnWrite` event to access the raw bytes. Or, you could write your own `TStream`-derived class that overrides the virtual `Write()` method.  Either way, you would be responsible for manually parsing and buffering the raw body data as they are being written to the stream.
- Otherwise, you may have to resort to using `TIdTCPClient` instead, implementing the HTTP protocol manually, then you would be solely responsible for reading in the HTTP response body however you want.

Comment: Ok, i will get into lead. and research. thanks remy.