How to get PDF attachment in XML mime?
How can I convert the content extracted from the XML below into a PDF?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.cnj.jus.br/tipos-servico-intercomunicacao-2.2.2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.cnj.jus.br/servico-intercomunicacao-2.2.2/" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:entregarManifestacaoProcessualResposta>
            <ns1:sucesso>true</ns1:sucesso>
            <ns1:mensagem>Teste</ns1:mensagem>
            <ns1:protocoloRecebimento>191725535392660528665499995040</ns1:protocoloRecebimento>
            <ns1:dataOperacao>20240904141406</ns1:dataOperacao>
            <ns1:recibo>
                <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:urn:uuid:aff47352-d3fe-4d0c-9438-cefc8f75ae5e"/>
            </ns1:recibo>
        </ns2:entregarManifestacaoProcessualResposta>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

--urn:uuid:edc011d1-343f-47b5-aa9e-abb12c569b7d
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <urn:uuid:ac492684-ced9-4e91-8877-19c244032568>

%PDF-1.4
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/Group <</Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB>>
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 271>>........

I'm using Delphi XE2 (HTTPRIO) and apparently it doesn't support this type of XML file (MTOM). I tried editing the XML leaving only the content of "cid:", however, when generating the PDF it doesn't work.
How can I generate the PDF?
The MIME comes from a web service that I imported from a WSDL. I use HTTPRIO to send the XML and in the HTTPRIO1AfterExecute event, I get the SOAPResponse (XML).
I have tried several times to get the content directly from the XML (cid:) and I have tried to pass it to the stream, encode it to base64, decode it from base64, and the PDF that it generates is corrupted. I believe I am doing it wrong.
Below is one of the attempts I made (the last one, because I have already deleted and edited the rest several times):
slXSL1 := TStringList.Create;
slXSL1.LoadFromFile('C:\Teste\Resp.xml');

xml := '';
posIni := Pos('href', slXSL1.Text);
posFim := Pos('</ns1:recibo>', slXSL1.Text);
xml := copy(slXSL1.Text, posIni + 10, (posFim - posIni) - 13);

 Encoder := TIdEncoderMIME.Create;
 try Base64String := Encoder.Encode(xml);
 finally Encoder.Free;
 end;
 sPDF := Base64String;

 decoder := TIdDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
 stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
 decoder.DecodeStream(sPDF, stream);
 setString(utf8, PChar(stream.Memory), stream.Size);
 stream.SaveToFile('C:\Teste\Resp.PDF');

By editing the XML in the Receipt tag, I can make XE2 understand the XML and it returns the following information:

(186, 185, 238, 186, 39, 90, 215, 191, 58, 217, 238, 95, 123, 214, 248, 213, 198, 218, 215, 158, 223, 119, 126, 90, 225, 183, 250, 241, 173, 117)

However, I have already tried to convert this information into a memoryStream:
MemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
MemoryStream.Write(responseProcEproc.receipt, Length(responseProcEproc.receipt));
MemoryStream.Position := 0;
TBlobField(cdsFT_DOCUMENTO.FieldByName('DOCUMENTO_DOC')).LoadFromStream(MemoryStream);

It generates the PDF document with 1KB, being corrupted.
I have no experience with this type of file, and so I don't know how to proceed. I tried what I could and what I researched on the internet. Could you help me with an example or code?
Note: I'm trying to get the content of the response file and transform it into a PDF.

Where is the MIME coming from, exactly? How are you accessing it? What does your code look like that is not working? Please provide more detail.

And how would I do that? Could you show me some sample code?

Mime attachments are in the body of a HTML message and each attachment starts with two dashes on a new line.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)

Thanks for the help, I already knew that. My question is how to save the file (PDF) attached to the XML.

It's a bit unclear from your question, but it sounds like the PDF is not embedded in the XML, but rather the XML and PDF are both contained within a multipart object. Find a multipart parser for your language and go from there.

So this attachment is inside the xml and it is a multipart/x-mixed-replace.

I added above what would be the encrypted PDF that comes with the XML. In fact, I tried to take this data and transform it into a memoryStream and try to build the PDF, without success.

Good evening and thank you again. In the XML, it has the %PDF, but I'm not able to edit it on the website here and add this piece of XML.
I just keep turning the edit button and it doesn't go up.

I managed to add a piece of code.

And if you use TIDHTTP like the example on this site:
https://www.indyproject.org/2014/03/05/new-tidhttp-honoreadmultipartmime-flag/
@Remy Lebeau would it be possible to download this content? If so, could you help me with an example?

@Spyke There is no base64 in the data you have shown, so do not involve TIdEncoderMIME/TIdDecoderMIME at all. The XML contains a cid: url to a resource outside of the XML. Evert is correct, you have a MIME response with 2 parts, the XML and the PDF. You need a MIME parser. Despite its name, TIdDecoderMIME is NOT a MIME parser, just a base64 parser (I'll have to rename it someday). You can use TIdMessageDecoderMIME instead. I've posted examples of that many times before (such as in the Indy blog post you linked to)...

@Spyke ... Decode the MIME to extract the XML content, and then parse the XML (Delphi has an XML parser, don't use TStringList) to pull out the CID. Then continue to decode the MIME to extract the PDF content for the corresponding CID. Basically, give TIdMessageDecoderMIME a TStream with the MIME data, and then call its ReadHeaders() and ReadBody() methods in a loop to access each MIME part.

@Spyke "And if you use TIDHTTP like the example on this site: https://www.indyproject.org/2014/03/05/new-tidhttp-honoreadmultipartmime-flag/ … would it be possible to download this content?" - yes. Are you having trouble following the example in that article?

In your example, which I saw in another question here on the site (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66728692/delphi-indy-tidhttp-and-multipart-x-mixed-replace-with-text-and-jpeg-image), it saves in JPG. I was able to adapt part of the code, but I couldn't change that part from JPG to PDF.
Here's how I did it:

try BodyStream.Position := 0; PDFStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try PDFStream.Write(Pointer(BodyStream)^, BodyStream.Size); //PDFStream.CopyFrom(BodyStream, BodyStream.Size);
{SS := TStringStream.Create(''); SS.CopyFrom(BodyStream, 0);
PDFStream.Write(Pointer(BodyStream)^, Length(SS.DataString));}
PDFStream.SaveToFile('C:\Fiorilli\SIA7\XML_Peticionamento\Recibo.PDF');
SS.Free;
finally PDFStream.Free;
FreeAndNil(Decoder);
Decoder := TIdMessageDecoderMIME.Create(nil);
TIdMessageDecoderMIME(Decoder).MIMEBoundary := Boundary;
end;
finally
BodyStream.Free;
end;

It is not saving correctly, it appears as corrupted.
